Expectation value of position in first-order perturbation
Suppose I have a simple harmonic oscillator in ground state and a time-dependent perturbation $V(t)=f(t) \hat{x}$ that turns on at $t=0$. How do I find the expectation value of position in t goes to infinity limit?
I know how to calculate the transition amplitude $c_n(t\to\infty)$ for example. But how to find expectation of $x$?

Basically you need to solve a Schrödinger equation $[H_{0}+\lambda V(t)]|\psi (t)\rangle =i\hbar {\frac {\partial |\psi (t)\rangle }{\partial t}}$ for substituting solutions into position expectation value: $\overline x = \int x |\Psi(x,t)|^2~dx$. Strong perturbation theory, Perturbation Theory II: Time Dependent Case, and many other sources. Overall,- it's not a trivial operation.

In this problem there is an exact expression for the expectation of $\hat{x}$. I assume that you are well acquainted with the usual method of treating the harmonic oscillator problem in quantum theory. In terms of ladder operators we have
$$
\hat{x} = c(b+b^\dagger), \quad \hat{H}(t) = \hbar\omega(b^\dagger b + 1/2) + cf(t)(b+b^\dagger)
$$
where $c$ is some constant that can be explicitly expressed through the parameters $\hbar$, $\omega$, $m$. For this type of Hamilton operator $\hat{H}(t)$, it is natural to look for a solution of the Schrödinger equation
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|t\rangle = \hat{H}(t)|t\rangle
$$
in the form of a coherent state
$$
|t\rangle = A(t)\exp(\phi(t)b^\dagger)|0\rangle
$$
with the initial conditions $A(0)=1$, $\phi(0) = 0$. Using the properties of the ladder operators $b$, $b^\dagger$, it is not difficult to obtain the following equations for the functions $A(t)$, $\phi(t)$:
$$
i\hbar\dot{\phi}(t) = \hbar\omega\phi(t) + cf(t),\quad
i\hbar\dot{A}(t) = A(t)(cf(t)\phi(t)+\hbar\omega/2)
$$
and the formula for the required expectation:
$$
\langle\hat{x}\rangle(t) = c(\phi(t)+\phi^*(t)).
$$
From the first of these equations we have
$$
\phi(t) = \frac{c}{i\hbar}\int\limits_0^t f(t')e^{i\omega(t'-t)}dt'
$$
and
$$
\langle\hat{x}\rangle(t) = \frac{2c^2}{\hbar}\int\limits_0^t f(t')\sin(\omega(t'-t)) dt'
$$
Given an explicit expression, we can try to analyze the behavior of $\langle\hat{x}\rangle(t)$ as $t\to\infty$.
